# Docker-compose build running out of memory

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a php-apache container for a legacy app with following features:

- actual git controlled project is mounted to the container
- the container runs as the host user (taking the uid and gid) to overcome permission issues
- the project has few interconnected sites, so we're opening a few ports to make it easier to access them from host machine.

This is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    env_file:
      - ./docker/docker.env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/mysql/Dockerfile
      network: host
    user: '74:74'
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: on-failure
  php:
    env_file:
      - ./docker/docker.env
    build:
      args:
        - USER_ID=${USER_ID}
        - GROUP_ID=${GROUP_ID_WWW}
        - USER=cakephp
        - PWD=password
        - HTTP_PROXY=${HTTP_PROXY}
        - HTTPS_PROXY=${HTTPS_PROXY}
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
      network: host
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "9080:80"
      - "9081:80"
      - "9082:80"
      - "9083:80"
    volumes:
      - ./bakery:/var/www/html
      - ./bakery-assets:/var/www/assets
      - ./bakery-live:/var/www/local-live
      - ./bakery-preview:/var/www/local-preview
      - ./docker/apache/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./docker/php/tmp:/tmp/xdebug
    restart: on-failure
networks:
  hostnet:
    external: true
    name: host
```

and here is the dockerfile for php service:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

ARG USER_ID=123456
ARG GROUP_ID=70
ARG USER=cakephp
ARG PWD=password
ARG HTTP_PROXY
ARG HTTPS_PROXY

ENV http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}
ENV https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY}

# creating user with host user UID and _www user GID
# www-data details on docker container: uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
RUN groupadd -r --gid=70 apache
RUN useradd -Mr apache --uid=70 --gid=70
#RUN groupadd -r --gid=70 cakephp
RUN useradd -Mr cakephp --uid=123456 --gid=70
# we do not need home directory for the cakephp user (so using -M switch)
# using the -l log when the uid or gid is a large number. otherwise it ends up in error: write /var/log/lastlog: no space left on device
RUN useradd -M cakephp --uid=123456 --gid=70 --groups=sudo -l && echo "cakephp:password" | chpasswd

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER=cakephp
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP=apache

RUN if [ "${HTTP_PROXY}" != "" ]; then \
    # needed as we're behind proxy
    pear config-set http_proxy ${HTTP_PROXY} \
;fi

# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install apt-utils -y --no-install-recommends

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    g++ \
    libicu-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    openssl \
    pkg-config \
    vim \
    zip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    && apt-get clean
#    && apt-get clean \
#    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# COPY apache/conf/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
# ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /path/to/new/root
# RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
# RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# images ships with php.ini-development and php.ini-production config files
# use the default production configuration
#RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
RUN cp "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    curl \
    gd \
    intl \
    mbstring \
    mysqli \
    opcache \
    pdo \
    sockets

#RUN docker-php-ext-configure bcmath --enable-bcmath
#    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
#    && docker-php-ext-configure mbstring --enable-mbstring \

# Set timezone
RUN ln -snf "/usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE}" /etc/localtime && echo "${TIMEZONE}" > /etc/timezone
RUN printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "%s"\n', "${TIMEZONE}" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini
RUN "date"

# enable bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-configure bcmath --enable-bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath

# enable ldap
RUN docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    && docker-php-ext-install ldap

# enable pdo mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# enable zip
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

# override with custom settings
# install xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# enable short tag. php ini is in /usr/local/etc/php directory.
# RUN sed -ri -e 's!/usr/local/etc/php/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# RUN echo ${HTTP_PROXY}
# RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -x http://dev-server-proxy.cmc.local:3128 | php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
#RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -x ${HTTP_PROXY} | php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
# RUN composer --version
# RUN composer install

WORKDIR /var/www/html/httpdocs
# USER ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID}
# USER cakephp

ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/www/
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2/

CMD whoami
CMD id cakephp
```

When trying to build php service, it runs out of space and running 'docker system df' returns output like this:

```
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              14                  0                   5.236GB             5.236GB (100%)
Containers          1                   0                   295GB               295GB (100%)
Local Volumes       0                   0                   0B                  0B
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

I don't understand how come a php container build process could use up 295GB and possibly more. Is it problem with my Docker build process or an issue with docker.

I've trying running 'docker system prune' and 'docker volume prune' and restarting docker, but it always ends up like this.

I'd appreciate help on this. Thanks.

Comment: I also don't understand how the containers could take up 295GB where the host has a SSD sized 250GB. It doesn't have any other storage attached. And has 16GB RAM. It's running on Mac OS, Catalina. System is running behind a proxy.

Comment: When you start building your image, docker sends your current folder to the docker daemon. It also prints out the size of that folder. How much is it? Normally docker build fails this way when you for example build your image from the root directory (`/`)

Comment: I'm running it from a project directory, which is not root, and is inside my home directory. The size of that directory is 7.24GB, because it has the project files and also the mysql db data directory.

Comment: This indeed doesn't explain the 256Gb. However, I recommend you to move the database directory somewhere else or to add it to .dockerignore. Can you do a `docker container ls` and post the answer?

Comment: Thanks Mihai, this is the result from docker container ls (I'm using the db service at the moment, so it's listed here):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
c137fd632e3e        docker_db           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 hours ago        Up 25 hours         0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   docker_db_1
```

Comment: sorry, it's not formatting the code block.

Comment: so it's only the database that takes all the space. On which operating system are you? It might be that you need to increase the space allocated to your VM that is running the docker daemon

Comment: I've added `db_data` directory and all the codebase directories to `.dockerignore` file and trying again. Usually the docker process fails when running the Dockerfile from php service and it comes to `RUN useradd -Mr cakephp --uid=xxx --gid=xxx` part.

I'm on MacOS, Catalina. I've 60GB allocated to docker.

Comment: Didn't actually work with `.gitignore`. It still runs out of memory when trying to build php service.